# Can't get returned value from an 'async' function - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am working with some asynchronous functions in javascript, but I am facing a problem, that I already posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428862/constructor-function-isnt-get-call-after-a-specific-wait-javascript) but that was a bit unpractical experience for everyone. Now, I made a simple constructor function with same member functions inside and returned a value, but seems like same problem to me, I tried my best but I don't know what is the problem, if you run this code then You can check what I want. Here's the [demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/83s42wex/) on JSfiddle, where you can see the results on `console`.

**This is my Code**

```js
function Test() {
  this.init = async function() {
    var count = 0,
      page_job_details = null;

    async function waitMore() {
      console.log("Wait more loaded - " + (count + 1) + "...");
      let p = new Promise(function(res, rej) {
        setTimeout(async function() {
          if (count === 2) {
            res({
              page_job_details: "khan"
            });
          } else {
            count++;
            waitMore();
          }
        }, 2000);
      });
      var res = await p;
      if (res.page_job_details === '' || res.page_job_details === 'undefined' || res.page_job_details === null) {
        console.log("waiting more...");
        waitMore();
      } else {
        console.log("Response is : " + res.page_job_details);
        return res;
      }
    }
    var khan;
    await waitMore().then(function(r) {
      console.log(r);
      khan = r;
    });
    return khan;
  }
}
new Test().init().then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
})
```

> When you comment out the conditions within the `setTimeout()` and simply `res({page_job_details:"khan"});` then you'll get the results in the `new Test().init().then(function(res){ console.log(res); })`. Otherwise not, and that's the main problem.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain what sort of output you were expecting instead?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am expecting the answer in the `res`, when the `Test().init()` is called.

Comment: You're receiving "khan" at the end of the promise, is not what you want?

Comment: @MiguelAngel It's not being chained to the end `.init().then` section

Comment: I want the results returned by the `init()` @MiguelAngel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the issues is that you are not returning the result of the recursive call from within the promise.

Instead of just calling it recursively

```
waitMore();
```

you seem to expect the result of the recursive call to be returned down the pipeline

```
res(waitMore());
```

```js
function Test() {
  this.init = async function() {
    var count = 0,
      page_job_details = null;

    async function waitMore() {
      console.log("Wait more loaded - " + (count + 1) + "...");
      let p = new Promise(function(res, rej) {
        setTimeout(async function() {
          if (count === 2) {
            res({
              page_job_details: "khan"
            });
          } else {
            count++;
            res(waitMore());
          }
        }, 2000);
      });
      var res = await p;
      if (res.page_job_details === '' || res.page_job_details === 'undefined' || res.page_job_details === null) {
        console.log("waiting more...");
        waitMore();
      } else {
        console.log("Response is : " + res.page_job_details);
        return res;
      }
    }
    var khan;
    await waitMore().then(function(r) {
      console.log(r);
      khan = r;
    });
    return khan;
  }
}
new Test().init().then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
})
```

Comment: Perfect Results, can you explain it a bit to me technically; why the results of `console.log("Response is : " + res.page_job_details);` is three times displayed ? in the `else` part .

Comment: Three seems to be the level of your recursion.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

- Inside `waitMore`'s `setTimeout`, `res` is only called if `count === 2`. Otherwise, the created promise never resolves, and whatever might be `await`ing `waitMore()` will never resolve - instead, that thread will remain suspended forever. You can fix this by calling `res` *regardless* of whether `count` is `2` or not - if the `count` is *less* than `2`, call `res` with *another invocation* of `waitMore`:

  ```
  res(waitMore());
  ```
- On the level of the `this.init` function, in the case that you need to wait more, you need to `await waitMore()` (and put the response in a new variable that gets returned) so as to chain the Promise properly:

  ```
  if (res.page_job_details === '' || res.page_job_details === 'undefined' || res.page_job_details === null) {
    console.log("waiting more...");
    const newRes = await waitMore();
    return newRes;
  }
  ```

```js
function Test() {
  this.init = async function() {
    var count = 0,
      page_job_details = null;

    async function waitMore() {
      console.log("Wait more loaded - " + (count + 1) + "...");
      const p = new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          if (count === 2) res({ page_job_details: "khan" });
          else {
            count++;
            res(waitMore());
          }
        }, 2000);
      });
      const res = await p;
      if (res.page_job_details === '' || res.page_job_details === 'undefined' || res.page_job_details === null) {
        console.log("waiting more...");
        const newRes = await waitMore();
        return newRes;
      } else {
        console.log("Response is : " + res.page_job_details);
        return res;
      }
    }
    var khan;
    await waitMore().then(function(r) {
      console.log(r);
      khan = r;
    });
    console.log('about to return from init')
    return khan;
  }
}
new Test().init().then(function(res) {
  console.log('in init callback')
  console.log(res);
})
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you for your answer !